# Draw collided transparent circles with the same color of common area

Tags: javascript, canvas

When i draw circles of the same color one by one using fill() for each circle. It comes that when they are overlapped, common are color is darker (saturated). 
See example 1 (left) [in JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/tiyafuguxa/1/edit?html,output).

If i create long path and then use fill() for this common path, it has strange artifacts (yep, of course it's confused by complex path and don't know what i'm trying to draw) 
See example 2 (right) [in JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/tiyafuguxa/1/edit?html,output).

How i can achieve that common area of circles with the same color was not saturated, it shoud be not darker than other circles with the same color. (exactly what i have [in JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/tiyafuguxa/1/edit?html,output) right side, but without crazy artifacts)

If circles with different colors has common areas, color should be saturated.

Comment: As you can see, some of coliding circles have the same colors some not. And collided circles of the same color should stay of the same color, when they covered by circle of the other color, color need to be saturated.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Regarding your `.getImageData` solution ...

It's faster to use compositing rather than `.getImageData` to blend your colors.

Here's a function to combine overlapping semi-transparent circles without having the overlap darken.

- Draw all identically colored circles on a 2nd canvas in an opaque color.
- Set `context.globalCompositeOperation='source-in'` which causes new drawings to replace existing pixels.
- Fill the 2nd canvas with the desired semi-transparent color for this set of indentically colored circles.

The result is a set of overlapping circles without the darkening effect.

```
function uniformColorCircles(circles){
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
    tempctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
    tempctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    tempctx.beginPath();
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
        var c=circles[i];
        tempctx.arc(c.x,c.y,c.radius,0,PI2);
    }
    tempctx.fillStyle='black';
    tempctx.fill();
    tempctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
    tempctx.fillStyle=circles[0].rgba;
    tempctx.fill();
}
```

And here is example code and a Demo involving multiple sets of semi-transparent circles:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

ctx.fillRect(0,0,120,220);

var tempCanvas=canvas.cloneNode();
var tempctx=tempCanvas.getContext('2d');

var c1={x:100,y:200,radius:50,rgba:'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'};
var c2={x:100,y:240,radius:35,rgba:'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'};
var c3={x:140,y:200,radius:50,rgba:'rgba(0,255,255,0.5)'};
var c4={x:140,y:240,radius:35,rgba:'rgba(0,255,255,0.5)'};
var c5={x:120,y:140,radius:50,rgba:'rgba(255,255,0,0.5)'};
uniformColorCircles([c1,c2]);
ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0);
uniformColorCircles([c3,c4]);
ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0);
uniformColorCircles([c5]);
ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,0,0);


function uniformColorCircles(circles){
    var PI2=Math.PI*2;
    tempctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
    tempctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
    tempctx.beginPath();
    for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
        var c=circles[i];
        tempctx.arc(c.x,c.y,c.radius,0,PI2);
    }
    tempctx.fillStyle='black';
    tempctx.fill();
    tempctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-in';
    tempctx.fillStyle=circles[0].rgba;
    tempctx.fill();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem using helper canvases and canvas image data processing.

There are data array, which contains coordinates and value which is used to determine which color we need to use.

I draw each circle color in it's own layer, then process each layer with preventSaturation function. Then add all layers into original canvas.

Please if anyone know the better way let me know.

If someone didn't understand what i needed to do it was:
1) i had [this](https://jsbin.com/mixidevova/edit?html,output) 
2) i tried to have [this](https://jsbin.com/mixidevova/1/edit?html,output)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('circles');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var radius = 30;
var opacity = .7;

var data = [
    {
        x: 200,
        y: 200,
        v: 10
    },
    {
        x: 230,
        y: 230,
        v: 20
    },
    {
        x: 250,
        y: 210,
        v: 30
    },
    {
        x: 270,
        y: 190,
        v: 40
    },
    {
        x: 300,
        y: 220,
        v: 100
    },
    {
        x: 300,
        y: 260,
        v: 200
    },
    {
        x: 320,
        y: 210,
        v: 300
    },
    {
        x: 300,
        y: 160,
        v: 200
    },
    {
        x: 380,
        y: 160,
        v: 3000
    },
    {
        x: 380,
        y: 110,
        v: 3000
    },
    {
        x: 320,
        y: 190,
        v: 3000
    }
];

var styles = {
    blue: {
        edgeValue: 0,
        color: [0, 0, 255, 0.7]
    },
    green: {
        edgeValue: 100,
        color: [0, 255, 0, 0.7]
    },
    red: {
        edgeValue: 1000,
        color: [255, 0, 0, 0.7]
    }
};

var layers = {};

for (var prop in styles) {
    if(styles.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

        var c = document.createElement('canvas');
        c.width = canvas.width;
        c.height = canvas.height;

        var cx = c.getContext('2d');

        var cc = document.createElement('canvas');
        cc.width = radius * 2;
        cc.height = radius * 2;

        var ccx = cc.getContext('2d');

        var cColor = styles[prop].color;

        ccx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + cColor[0] + ',' + cColor[1] + ',' + cColor[2] + ',' + cColor[3] + ')';

        ccx.beginPath();
        ccx.arc(radius, radius, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ccx.closePath();
        ccx.fill();

        layers[prop] = {
            color: styles[prop].color,
            edgeValue: styles[prop].edgeValue,
            canvas: c,
            ctx: cx,
            canvasC: cc,
            ctxC: ccx,
            objects: []
        };

    }
}

data.forEach(function(o) {
    var layer = o.v < styles.green.edgeValue ? layers.blue : o.v < styles.red.edgeValue ? layers.green : layers.red;
    layer.ctx.drawImage(layer.canvasC, o.x, o.y);
    layer.objects.push(o);
});

for(prop in layers) {
    if(layers.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        var image = layers[prop].ctx
                .getImageData(0, 0, layers[prop].canvas.width, layers[prop].canvas.height);
        preventColorSaturation(image.data, layers[prop].color);
        layers[prop].ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);

        ctx.drawImage(layers[prop].canvas, 0, 0);
    }
}

function preventSaturation (d, s) {
    var rgb255 = raRGBA255(s);

    for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i += 4) {
        d[i] = Math.min(d[i], rgb255[0]);
        d[i + 1] = Math.min(d[i + 1], rgb255[1]);
        d[i + 2] = Math.min(d[i + 2], rgb255[2]);
        d[i + 3] = Math.min(d[i + 3], rgb255[3]);
    }
}

function raRGBA255 (s) {

    return [
        s[0],
        s[1],
        s[2],
        255 * s[3]
    ];
}

function raHexToRGB (s) {
    var hexREGEXP = /^#([0-9A-Za-z]{3,6})$/;
    var parsedHEX = s.match(hexREGEXP);

    if (!parsedHEX) {
        return [0, 0, 0];
    }

    return [
        parseInt(parsedHEX[1].slice(0, 2), 16),
        parseInt(parsedHEX[1].slice(2, 4), 16),
        parseInt(parsedHEX[1].slice(4), 16)
    ];
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Yes, there is a faster (more efficient) way of achieving your result -- see my answer.